# Multiple unix pipes not working

Tags: unix, pipe, netcat, fifo

This first pipeline works fine (printing "c"):

```
echo "a" | sed 's/a/b/' | sed 's/b/c/'
```

This one does not do what I expect (nothing gets printed when I feed an "a" into my fifo ):

```
mkfifo fifo;
cat fifo | sed 's/a/b/' | sed 's/b/c/'
```

However, if I remove the second "sed" command from the latter pipeline, I do get a "b" printed. I think my understanding of pipes and redirects must be too simplistic. **Can someone explain to me how to fix the 2nd case** so that I can run two successive commands on the contents of the fifo?

(note this isn't a problem specific to fifo, the same behavior occurs with netcat too. I posted a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/759561/netcat-server-output-with-multiple-greps) about netcat but got no answers)

Comment: Your code works for me.  Maybe, you could spell out more detail on how you "feed an 'a'" into your fifo.

Comment: As @John1024 said, [WorksForMe](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VNrxB.png).

Comment: Me too, no problem whatsoever.

Comment: `echo "a" >fifo`

Comment: It seems this is buffering related. What version of sed are you using? Mine is `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat 4.2.2 here. Provided by the package `sed`, version `4.2.2-4ubuntu1`. But this could potentially also be related to how the producer (`echo`/the shell you're using) is flushing its output stream, rather than the consumer (sed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-u` (`--unbuffered`) option of sed, so it writes it's output, instead of collecting it first for a fast, large write later.

`cat fifo | sed -u 's/a/b/' | sed -u 's/b/c/'`

`cat` is always unbuffered.

If it's not about `sed`, but some program with output buffering, but without options to disable it, there are tools that can help to force buffering off - see `man unbuffer` and `man stdbuf`.

If it's a shell script, it should be unbuffered by default: when a command creates output in the script, and exits, the output is flushed. Otherwise, you use unbuffer inside the shell script.

For background, see this [overview of stdio buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/).

Comment: Suppose instead of sed, I had my own custom script. What would I do in this case to avoid the buffering? Or should it be unbuffered by default?

Comment: Just some more followup - if I wanted to use perl regular expressions with buffering, it would go something like `nc -k -l 4458 |  perl -ne 's{HTTP}{FTP}g; $|++;print $_' | perl -ne 's{FTP}{RTSP}g; $|++;print $_' `

Comment: Yes, what do you mean? Is there a problem, or is it an example? Oh, and you can use `ssed -R` if you like `sed` with perl regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry, that was not a question. I apologize for not being clear, it was just another example of the same concept. Unfortunately it's too late for me to edit that comment. I didn't know sed could understand Perl regex. Perhaps I should start using that instead from now on.

Comment: Oh, no problem!